# How to search for values then modify the current value from the file if the value was found

Tags: java, file, file-handling

So say for example I have this file

[image]

I want my program to search for the title and respective author using the input from the user and then ask for replacement values. Then these replacements will change the current value in the file.

This is my current implementation:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SecondChild4 extends SecondParent
{
    public void edit(String sFileName, String sFileName2)
    {
    try
    {
        sFileName2 = "Second.txt";
        File nfile2 = new File("Second.txt");
        File file2 = new File("TempSecond.txt");

        FileReader reader2 = new FileReader(sFileName2);
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(reader2);
        FileWriter twriter2 = new FileWriter(file2);
        BufferedWriter tbw2 = new BufferedWriter(twriter2);

        String line2 = "";
        String edit2 = "";
        String btitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Title: ", "");
        String bauthor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Author: ", "");
            //how to search if value was found from the file?
        String btitle1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Replace with title: ", "");
        String bauthor1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Replace with author: ", "");

        line2 = br2.readLine();
        while(line2 != null){
        if (line2 == null)
        {
        // End of File 
        tbw2.close();
        br2.close();
        }
        else if(what condition to put here?)
        {
        System.out.println("Search found");
        edit = line2.replaceAll(btitle, btitle1);
        edit2 = line2.replaceAll(bauthor, bauthor1);        
        tbw1.append(edit);
        tbw1.append(",");
        tbw1.append(edit2);
        tbw1.append("\n");
        tbw2.write(edit);
        tbw2.write("\t");
        tbw2.write(edit2);
        tbw2.newLine();
        tbw1.close();
        tbw2.close();
        br1.close();
        br2.close();
        }

        else{
        tbw1.append(line1);
        tbw1.append("\n");
        tbw2.write(line2);
        tbw2.newLine();
        tbw1.close();
        tbw2.close();
        br1.close();
        br2.close();
        }
    }
        file2.delete();
        file2.renameTo(nfile2);
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    }
}
```

I made a temp file for the storage of the modified values and then delete the old file and rename the temp file according to the previous file's name. In the code I made, there are problems such as the file contents get empty(I am also saving it in csv but did not put the codes related to that here. When it comes to csv, only the first line of the previous file gets rewritten to the temp), the file don't get deleted and renamed.

I know there are lots of mistakes with my code. I'm pretty new to programming. Please help me :)

Comment: You need to indent your code properly. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yoQZN7SAfd8

Comment: You could create a properties file instead.

Comment: @mzedeler I'm sorry I'm still not done so I haven't fixed the indentions yet haha.

Comment: Correct indentation is necessary *while* coding in order to avoid errors, not something you do after just to make it look nice.

Comment: @mzedeler I'll take that advice. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it nicely by creating a **book.properties** file like

```
Title=Foo
Author=bar
```

Java code will be like :

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SecondChild4 {

    private InputStream inputStream;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SecondChild4 s = new SecondChild4();
        s.getPropValues();
    }

    public String getPropValues() {
        String result = "";
        try {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            String propFileName = "book.properties";

            inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);

            if (inputStream != null) {
                prop.load(inputStream);
            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
            }

            // get the property value and print it out
            String title = prop.getProperty("Title");
            String author = prop.getProperty("Author");

            result = "Book = " + author + " title " + title;
            System.out.println("current book details are " + result);

            // replace logic here
            prop.setProperty("Title", "Hamlet");
            prop.setProperty("Author", "William Shakespeare");

            System.out.println("after modification");
            result = "Book = " + prop.getProperty("Author") + " title " + prop.getProperty("Title");
            System.out.println("cuurrent book details are " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Output :

> current book details are Book = bar title Foo after modification
>
> current book details are Book = William Shakespeare title Hamlet

**Some things for you to remember while coding :**

1. Dont put everything in try catch block just for sake of avoiding exceptions,keep only part that actually throws that exception...not whole code.
2. call all close methods eg: buffereader.close() in finally block
3. Never, never, never throw an exception , instead catch it there itself.